# Three channel vs. grayscale image input to a CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, confusion-matrix

I am trying to mimic and build an image classification model described in a paper. At first I was using 100x100x3 images as input to the neural network. The model was giving very good accuracy (~95%) in training phase, but producing very poor predictions, resulting in a confusion matrix that had same values in all cells. But when I trained the model with single band grayscale images as input, as done in the paper itself, the accuracy reduced to ~84% but the model made good predictions with good confusion matrix. I am building the CNN model with keras and using ImageDataGenerator for flowing images.

This is how I create image augmentation.(same as described in the paper):

```
# Flip image along y=x line: returns flipped image as an integer array
def flip_xy(img):
    img_flip = tfimg.rot90(np.flipud(PIL.Image.fromarray(img).resize((100,100))))
    return np.array(img_flip)

# Rotate img thrice by 90 degrees: returns 3 rotated images as integer arrays
def rotate90(img):
    img90 = tfimg.rot90(np.array(img.resize((100,100))))
    img180 = tfimg.rot90(np.array(img90))
    img270 = tfimg.rot90(np.array(img180))
    return np.array(img90), np.array(img180), np.array(img270)

# Crop image once from each corner and once from centre: return image object
def getCrops(img):
    upper_left = img.crop((10,10,110,110))
    upper_right = img.crop((0,10,100,110))
    lower_left = img.crop((10,0,110,100))
    lower_right = img.crop((0,0,100,100))
    centre = img.crop((5,5,105,105))
    return upper_left, upper_right, lower_left, lower_right, centre

# Create 40 copies from single image: data augmentation
def createCopies(img_path, target_folder):
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size = (110,110))
    img_file = img_path.split("\\")[-1].split(".")[0]
    k = 1
    ul, ur, ll, lr, ctr = getCrops(img)
    for image0 in [ul, ur, ll, lr, ctr]:
        i90, i180, i270 = rotate90(image0)
        for image1 in [i90, i180, i270, np.array(image0)]:
            flip = flip_xy(image1)
            PIL.Image.fromarray(image1).save(os.path.join(target_folder, f"{img_file}({k}).jpg"))
            PIL.Image.fromarray(flip).save(os.path.join(target_folder, f"{img_file}({k+1}).jpg"))
            k += 2
```

I then iterate over all the original images, creating augmentations.

Here is the code for model training:
[Model training](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GpAWAy353dv5Ia8eHZWCGJJrY2OhnZl7?usp=sharing). Ignore the fact that the training phase is not completed in the notebook. It is from a later run. In the original run, the training ran for all 30 epochs.

Here is the code for model evaluation:
[Model evaluation](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BzYC9l5yhRml53SbrKBc2E-mU0fQqbBG?usp=sharing). Here I have a second doubt. Why does predicting each image individually and predicting the generator object produce different results?

Can anyone explain why this happens? Shouldn't three channel images be able to train the model better? And why is there a discrepancy between model accuracy while training and actual predictions?

Comment: maybe your initial model overfit your data, did you use any form of validation to monitor overfitting?

Comment: First, it would be better to shqre some code. Especially for the pre-processing of your image in both cases. It may be possible that you didn't do the same processing pipeline for the new images

Comment: Hi @DominikFicek. The model has one Dropout layer with dropout rate=0.5. And I am using a validation set as well as early stopping. The early stopping also did not work in case of RGB input. The training ran for max epochs given (30). But it stopped at 10th epoch when using single band images

Comment: Hi @RedaElHail. I have done preprocessing on the RGB images itself. I created augmented images using original RGB images. I am using keras ImageDataGenerator for passing images to the model. When the rgb input didn't work, I passed grayscale images using colormode="grayscale" parameter of ImageDataGenerator. I hope this is clear enough. Let me know if you need any more information. The python code notebooks are very large. I don't know how to post specific codes.

Comment: @Himank It would be very helpful to add the most important parts of your code to the question. You can edit your post by clicking on Edit.  Here is a link to see how to embed code in a stackoveflow post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow

Comment: Okay @RedaElHail , I will do that.